# Get Data From SQL Server With PHP (Interest Object)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I will get data from mssql. But there is a schema between db and table. So I didn't get any data :/ I first time connecting mssql with Php.

How can I work my requests? Where should I write the schema(dbo).waiting your helps

**MY DB**

[image]

**MY REQUEST**

```
<?php
$conn=odbc_connect("DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=".$ser.";UID=".$user.";PWD=".$pass.";
DATABASE=".$db.";
Address=".$ser.",1433","","");

echo  "Connection: $conn";

if ($conn <= 0) { echo "Error"; exit; }
else { echo "Success"; };


$kayitlar = odbc_exec($conn,"Select * From LG_001_ITEMS LIMIT 10");

while($kayit = odbc_fetch_array($kayitlar)){

    echo $kayit["NAME"]."<br>";
}
?>
```

**ANSWER**

This request solved connection problem and get data array.

```
$sql="select dbo.LG_001_ITEMS.NAME from dbo.LG_001_ITEMS ORDER BY LOGICALREF OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
$result=odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die (odbc_errormsg());
$row=odbc_fetch_array($result);

while ($row) {
    print_r($row);

  }
```

**BUT NOW :(**

I can't get data from array. It show "ARRAY=>[]..." . What can I do?

**AND SOLVE**

```
$conn=odbc_connect("DRIVER=SQL Server;SERVER=".$ser.";UID=".$user.";PWD=".$pass.";
DATABASE=".$db.";
Address=".$ser.",1433","","");

echo  "Bağlantı: $conn";

if ($conn <= 0) { echo "Başarısız"; exit; }
else { echo "Başarılı"; };

$sql="select * from dbo.LG_001_ITEMS ORDER BY LOGICALREF OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";
$result=odbc_exec($conn, $sql) or die (odbc_errormsg());

$row=odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

if(!$row){exit("Hata");}
else{
    echo "<br>++<br>";
while(odbc_fetch_row($row)){
$sonuc=odbc_result($row,"NAME");
    echo $sonuc."<br>";
}


}
```

THANKS everyone

Comment: Why the MySQL tag?

Comment: sorry, I accidentally added

Comment: 1. does the connection work at all? 2. there is no "limit" in ms sql. Use "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM ..." instead 3. It should not be needed to include the schema in the select statement.

Comment: I did work it. Request is; $sql="select dbo.LG_001_ITEMS.NAME from dbo.LG_001_ITEMS ORDER BY LOGICALREF OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY";  but I didn't fetch $row :( it show ARRAY=>[] :(

Comment: @j.kaspar Now what can I do ? (I added problem in my message)

Comment: @Yunus I suppose, that the data are there. It is really hard to tell what could be wrong. Only thing I see is, that in `select dbo.LG_001_ITEMS.NAME from`, the dbo.LG_001_ITEMS is completely superfluous.

Comment: thank you @j.kaspar , I solved and add to end of question